# Добавление товара в корзину .build Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mvc

У меня есть список товаров, у каждого товара кнопка добавления в корзину, которая редиректит на путь контроллера line_items.

Код экшена из *line_items_controller.rb*

```
    def create
      item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
      @line_item = @cart.line_items.build(item: item)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @line_item.save
          format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully added.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
```

Какой хеш нужно передать в *.build()*, чтобы товар добавился в корзину?

По идее, нужно передать хеш параметров товара, но как бы я не пытался передать его, не выходит.
Сейчас выдает ошибку *can't write unknown attribute `item_id`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. 
Суть заключалась в неправильном файле миграции *line_items*, т.к. указал неверное имя.

Вместо `t.references :item` было прописано `t.references :product`

Так что я сделал `rake db:rollback` и исправил файл миграции.